# Report item expressions can only refer to fields within the current data set scope

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix

The Filter expression for the tablix 'Table1' refers to the field 'Bill'. Report item expressions can only refer to fields within the current data set scope or, if inside an aggregate, the specified  data set scope. Letters in the names of fields must use the correct case.

In my SSRS report the Parameter in the First Data set is using the values coming from Second Data set.

Can I know to fix this problem.

Answer (score 0):

This was due to your first dataset (A) is dependent to the second dataset (B) value.
Dataset in SSRS in being loaded from top to bottom, so try changing the dataset B to the uppermost so it will be loaded before using as a filter to the Dataset A.

Your Dataset should look like this.

Datasets
- B
- A